# Best approach for large data handling with status from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest

I am looking a proper solution to implement the below scenario.

I have a large amount of json data to process, previously the whole data is send to the server using rest apis and server perform certain action on each json row, after a very long time server sends the response back with the processing status of each row. but this approach always make the user confused, whether it is processing or not (because they are seeing the loading screen for over a 10 mins), since i am using rest apis I can't get any status while processing the data.

I am looking

1. Is there any good way to send the data in small batches ?
2. how can I get the status from server while processing the data ?

my frontend is ReactJS and backend is nodejs

Answer (score 0):

As per your given situation. You can use the pagination and send the data in a limited number of data packets.
If the user wants more data he can click on the next or previous data. In this case, I would suggest ANTD library. It works perfectly for pagination. For your reference here is the link for the trial.

You can also refer to this codeSandbox by Andrew Guo.

https://codesandbox.io/s/m4lj7l2yq8?file=/src/index.js

https://ant.design/components/pagination/

AS you mentioned the data is taking too long, for this I may suggest indexing in the database.And you can show Suspence until the whole data is loaded. This may help the user to understand that the data is been loaded.
Here is the link for your reference

https://ant.design/components/spin/

Comment: Hi Nikhil, thanks